# Можно ли полагаться на точность указываемых курсов валют в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Известно, что в `Google Play` для разного рода покупок цена может отображаться Пользователям в валюте их страны. Можно ли полагаться (*быть уверенным в точном соответствии реальной цены, установленной Разработчиком и реально показываемой Пользователю, в соответствии с курсом валюты в отдельно взятой стране*) на точность указываемых курсов валют?

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос, что такое "полагаться" в вашем контексте? Или пример

Comment: @Kromster: пожалуйста

Comment: Все равно не очень понятна формулировка. Пусть цена установленая на приложение 10уе, в рублях будет соответствовать 563.9р. Каким именно образом вы хотели бы полагаться на это? Пользоваться GP для определения курсов валют, смотря на цены приложений в разных валютах? Обещать пользователям из разных стран стоимость приложения смотря на курсы их валют к уе? Как-то еще?

Comment: @Kromster: просто знать об этом как минимум

Comment: Поэтому и прошу уточнения, так как непонятно, знать "о чем"? Я так понимаю, что вы встретили расхождение и решили его зафиксировать на ruSO - это отлично. Но для других читателей полезно так же знать более полный контекст (да и в поисковиках будет лучше искаться)

Comment: @Kromster: Вот скаканул курс $ в некоторой стране, цена на приложение указана одна, предъявляется к оплате другая. Google ведь снимает с себя какую-либо отвественность, согласно пункту в ответе. А кому посыпятся вопросы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше не полагаться.

Согласно [Соглашению Google Play о распространении программных продуктов](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ru/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html) Статья 3 (*Ценообразование и платежи*) пункт 3.2

> 3.2 Продукты предлагаются пользователям от Вашего имени по ценам, которые Вы определяете по собственному усмотрению. Google может
>   включать соответствующие налоги в цену, которая будет предложена
>   пользователям в Google Play. Вы можете устанавливать цены на Продукты
>   в валюте, одобренной Вашим Партнером по обработке платежей. **Google
>   может показывать пользователям цены на Продукты в валютах их стран, не
>   принимая на себя ответственности за точность валютных курсов**.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю из документации:

> При оформлении заказа сумма в валюте покупателя конвертируется в валюту вашего аккаунта Google по текущему обменному курсу.
>
> Конвертация производится в момент оплаты заказа, а обменный курс указывается в квитанции для каждого приложения.

В английской версии документации указано также, что:

> This rate updates throughout the day
>
> Этот обменный курс обновляется в течении дня

Полагаю, что для расчета обменного курса используется тот же движок, что и в [Google Finance Currency Converter](https://finance.google.com/finance/converter)

Comment: [прочитал](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1169947?hl=en), спасибо. Я правильно понимаю (оттуда) , конвертация курса происходит в момент оформления заказа, а не в момент вывода Пользователю цены за Продукт?